# Enable Lenovo's "conservation mode" on boot

Tags: windows-8, power-management, lenovo-laptop, battery-life

I have a Lenovo Z50 laptop with Lenovo's Energy Manager installed. Inside the manager's settings menu is an option to enable "conservation mode", which keeps the battery charged in the 40-65% range when charged, to preserve the battery life.

Unfortunately, this mode is always disabled on booting. I'd like to find a way to have it enabled on booting. (If you know a way to enable it through a command-line command or something like that, that would be OK too!)

Comment: Which version of Lenovo's Energy Manager are you using, Windows 8 or Windows 7?

Comment: Version 1.0.0.35, on Windows 8.1.

Comment: This question is very specific to Lenovo's software, which I do not have. Sorry I don't have an answer, but I did find this information which may be useful to you. [Changing Default Energy Management Options...](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Changing-Default-Energy-Management-Options/m-p/587111#M45460)

Answer (score 2):

Create a directory -- C:\EM8\Log -- and toggle the conservation mode setting in Energy Manager. The setting should persist after a reboot.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  This answer would be even better if you edit it to provide some explanation as to *why* your solution addresses the OPs question.

Comment: I see that there are now logs created in that folder, but the setting still doesn't persist after reboots.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me. 
Below the clock thingy on energy manager it says you're either on: stable, power saving, balanced or high perfomance mode. If your laptop is on high performance mode then you have to change it to one of the other settings. After you do that, enable conservation mode and then restart your laptop.

After your laptop has been restarted conservation mode should still be on, and after that you can put your laptop back on high performance mode. Restart you laptop one more time and then you can see that your laptop is running on high performance mode and conservation mode when you look at your settings in energy manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the little arrow on the right near the clock, ( sorry to the tech savvy,) and set it to conservation mode there, then to make this change permanent (I have read some weird and wonderful answers while I've been looking for the answer myself,) is to take the plug out and let the battery run down, when it is below 60% put the power plug back in.

When you restart you will no longer see the battery power warning

Comment: I'm unable to find this arrow. Could you provide a screenshot and/or more information?